# How can I replace multiple tables and text style within a range/selection in Word-VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

So, I am working with VBA on a word template which for every item (requirements in this case) contains a table with different specifications (all the tables are in the same format) and some other information. Below each table I have a text which shows the status of each item like: status: Approved or Work, or Rejected etc. I am asked to delete all the other statuses in the template and keep only the "Rejected" status and the whole information and table with that has this status to format in a light grey. Does anybody has any idea how to navigate to all tables, information, and specify the section I need to Format? I am very new to this and I am completely stucked! Here's some code I wrote:

```
Sub DeleteWorkflow()

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Italic = False
With Selection.Find.Replacement.ParagraphFormat
    .SpaceBefore = 0
    .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
    .SpaceAfter = 0
    .SpaceAfterAuto = False
End With
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Status: Approved"
    .Text = "Status: Work"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With


Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute
```

'Finds status "Rejected" and changes the font color

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Status: Rejected"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue
        .Font.ColorIndex = wdGray50
Selection.Find.Execute

End With
```

The code to find the rejected status and to change its color is not working and I am not getting it why. Any idea?

Comment: Would you have a sample of what the document looks like or an example we could see to  find a way to work around it ?

Comment: @Pierre I do not know why I can not provide an screenshot of a sample now but I will try to describe it as good as I can. So, just imagine a 4 column table regarding the item than after the table, below, on the left side the ID of the Item and on the right the status, eg: Status: Rejected.

Comment: Next lines are some text and this is repetitive for the other items which have the same or other statuses like work, in Analysis, approved etc. I should Keep only the status rejected on the template and delete the others. All the Information with rejected status should be formatted in Grey. I hope I was clear and thanks for your time :) @PierreChevallier

Answer (score 0):

**Basis of the idea**

The idea is to look through the [sentences of the word document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194403.aspx). Sentences comprise regular text and also text contained within tables.

As you load all the sentences in a single object in VBA, you can look through the content of the document sentences by sentences and perform an action on it.

We can also apply that type of search to [tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845117.aspx) within the document, if the text they contain match the characters you want.

**The code**

*For sentences*

```
Sub SENTENCE_CHANGE_COLOR()

Dim i As Long
Dim oSentences As Sentences
'Here we instantiate the variable oSentences to store all the values of the current opened document
Set oSentences = ThisDocument.Sentences

' We loop through every fields of the document
For i = 1 To oSentences.Count
    ' The property .Text contains the text of the item in it
    ' Then we just have to look for the text within the string of characters
    If InStr(oSentences.Item(i).Text, "Status: Rejected") Then
        'Do some stuff, like changing the color
        oSentences.Item(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdGray50
    else
        ' Do some other things like changing the color to a different color
        oSentences.Item(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdGray25
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

*For tables*

```
Sub TABLE_CHANGE_COLOR()

Dim i As Long
Dim oTables As Tables
'Here we instantiate the variable oTables to store all the tables of the current opened document
Set oTables = ThisDocument.Tables

' We loop through every fields of the document
For i = 1 To oTables.Count
    ' Finding the occurence of the text in the table
    If Not InStr(oTables.Item(i).Range.Text, "Status: Rejected") = 0 Then
        'Do some stuff, like changing the color
        oTables.Item(i).Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdGray50
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

*Combination of the above methods*

After we found the occurrence of a "Status: Rejected" document we can select the table right before it by comparing the table's end to the start of the occurrence.
Beware since the following code would modify **any table before "Status: rejected"**. So if "Status: rejected" is input in an incorrect location, it will modify the previous table wherever this table will be in the document.

```
Sub REJECTED_TABLE_CHANGE_COLOR()

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim oSentences As Sentences
Dim oTables As Tables

'Here we instantiate the variable oSentences to store all the values of the current opened document
Set oSentences = ThisDocument.Sentences
'Here we instantiate the variable oTables to store all the tables of the current opened document
Set oTables = ThisDocument.Tables

' We loop through every fields of the document
For i = 1 To oSentences.Count
    ' The property .Text contains the text of the item in it
    ' Then we just have to look for the text within the string of characters
    If InStr(oSentences.Item(i).Text, "Status: Rejected") Then
        ' When we have found the correct text, we try to find the table just above it
        ' We start from the last table
        ' This condition ensures we do not start looking for before the first table
        If oTables.Item(1).Range.End < oSentences.Item(i).Start Then
            j = oTables.Count
            While oTables.Item(j).Range.End > oSentences.Item(i).Start
                j = j - 1
            Wend
            oTables.Item(j).Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdGray50
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

This solution would provide you the basis to edit the document when the matching criteria is found within an item.

Comment: thank you very much. I tried it but it turns all the content of the document in Grey. What line of code should I write if I want to apply the if condition only to the rejected and do nothing to the other part with a different statuses. @pierre

Comment: Just remove the `else
        ' Do some other things like changing the color to a different color
        oSentences.Item(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdGray25` and it should apply the editing part to the sentence with the `Status : rejected` . I would suggest to see the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx) regarding the `if` syntax too. Keep in mind the above answer will just change the sentence to grey ( `wdGray50` as a matter of fact ) if it matches "Status: rejected" and not the table or paragraph.

Comment: Yes I noticed that. I mean how can I go back to the table and the rest of Information to format them in grey too. Is there any function in VBA that can send me to the table to make changes after applying your code to the rejected status? @Pierre

Comment: I just added a code snippet that looks for the content within the table and if it matches it changes the formatting of the whole table. However it will look only for the content **within the table**, would such a solution be effective ?

Comment: It doesnt work because the status is outside the table.

Comment: I added a code that would combine both the above techniques, thus meaning it would modify the previous table after finding the occurrence of "Status: rejected" .

Comment: yeap, this was something I needed also but the thing is the only section left without formating now is the text between the table with the status rejected and the next table which may have another status. After this the problem is solved. Thank you so so much!

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have your document so I cannot tell, but with the code above, by tweeking the elements you want to change the colour with the objects `oTable` and `oSentence` it is possible to do so.

Comment: `oSentences.Item(i + 1).Select
     oSentences.Item(i + 1).Font.ColorIndex = wdGray25
     
     If oTables.Item(i).Title = "ItemPropertiesTable" Then
     
     oTables.Item(i).Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdGray25
     oSentences.Item(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdGray25
     Else
     End If`                                                                                                                  How to organize this to work. I mean what changes to make so the formatting will be done until we reach the table with the name "ItemPropertiesTable"? @Pierre Chevallier